# How to give arrow image below a div when hover occurs?

Tags: css

**HTML**

```
<div id="aux_center_pnav" style="">
    <ul style="margin-top:2%;overflow: hidden;">
       <li class="DFSPLi aux_center_pnavli fl">高品性理念></li>
       <li class="DFSPLi aux_center_pnavli fl">规律治疗</li>
       <li class="DFSPLi aux_center_pnavli fl">ED与慢性疾病</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.aux_center_pnavli{
    padding: 2% 10.3%;
    background:#f5f5f7;
}
#aux_center_pnav li:hover{
/*background-color:#c4a2e7;*/
background:url("http://www.permits.performance.gov/sites/all/themes/permits/images/arrow.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 #c4a2e7;
color:white;
    background-position: left 300px top 35px;
}
```

Here is my jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/tAqd3/1/

When mouse over occurs arrow will show. But I need it below that div.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove overflow hidden from the ul, also should refactor the style attribute into an external css file

```
<div id="aux_center_pnav">
  <ul>
    <li class="DFSPLi aux_center_pnavli fl">高品性理念></li>
    <li class="DFSPLi aux_center_pnavli fl">规律治疗</li>
    <li class="DFSPLi aux_center_pnavli fl">ED与慢性疾病</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

make the li's relative and then position the arrow absolutely.

```
.aux_center_pnavli {
  padding: 2% 10.3%;
  background: #f5f5f7;
  position: relative;
}

#aux_center_pnav li:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: no-repeat scroll 0 0 #c4a2e7;
}

#aux_center_pnav li:hover:after {
  content: url("http://www.permits.performance.gov/sites/all/themes/permits/images/arrow.png");
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px; //half the width of the arrow to center it
}
```